# IOS background location info.plist key name

Tags: ios, core-location, info.plist

On IOS when asking for location permissions allways on, after some time the system propmpt to the user a dialog saying `the app whats to use the location in the background` or something like that.

how can i change the description of this dialog?
is it one of these?

```
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
```

Comment: See [Choosing the Authorization Level for Location Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services) **and** [Requesting Always Authorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization) **and** [Requesting When-In-Use Authorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_when_in_use_authorization)

Comment: @Honey This is not very helpful. the dialog pops after some time if the user clicked always allow in the dialog location permission.
on the first dialog i write to the user `please chose "always allow"` and when the thing with the background pops i want to write `please chose "continue"`

Answer (score 2):

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This string is required to gain permission to access location services on iOS 8+ when the app in the background and should describe how your app uses location services. Set this string in the Info.plist</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This string is optional but recommended on iOS 6 &amp; 7 and should describe how your app uses location services. Set this string in the Info.plist</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This string is required to gain permission to access location services on iOS 8+ and should describe how your app uses location services. Set this string in the Info.plist</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This string is required to gain permission to access location services on iOS 11+ and should describe how your app uses location services. Set this string in the Info.plist</string>
```